# Problems restoring file backed up on Windows using Duplicati to a Linux server running mono

Tags: linux, windows, duplicity, backup

TL/DR version:

Mono + Duplicati.commandline.exe restore etc. etc. spits this out for several files regardless of what I try. I am able to list sets, list files in said sets, even do a verify, but each time i do a restore of any kind, i get errors to the effect of :

> Failed to restore file: "snapshot/blahblah/2005-11-07.tar.gz", Error
>   message: The partial file record for
>   snapshot/blahblah/2005-11-07.tar.gz does not match the file

Any advice here, or an idea of where to look for a better solution?

FULL STORY:

Ive recently put together an nice clean, friendly backup solution for several servers, predominantly Linux, but occasionally a windows box is added too. The solution as is meets all my requirements and does it well... save 1: cross-compatibility

The solution is based on a combination of several elements, but eventually comes done to using Duplicity and Duplicati for the actual storage of files. The entire solution was ready to go before i realized that Duplicati, does not, in fact allow me to restore my files to a Linux box, regardless of what the commandline under Mono might tell you. It just spits out errors on random zip and image files, for apparently no good reason as i have tried several options to get it to restore, and several versions of Mono including installing it pretty much lib-for-lib. There is no effective log file for the reasons for these errors, and even the "--debug-output=true" flag does nothing.

I am able to list sets, list files in said sets, even do a verify, but each time i do a restore of any kind, i get errors to the effect of :

> Failed to restore file: "snapshot/blahblah/2005-11-07.tar.gz", Error
>   message: The partial file record for
>   snapshot/blahblah/2005-11-07.tar.gz does not match the file

Now i could most likely use the friendly instructions on Duplicati's site and script a bash equivalent of the restore, but that's not exactly ideal. Any advice on this? or possibly an alternative solution that presents the same benefits of Duplicati/Duplicity but that actually works across platforms?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a problem with restoring a Windows made backup on a Linux machine.
The problem should be fixed in 1.3 beta (r1020), but the details are here:
http://code.google.com/p/duplicati/issues/detail?id=482

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you created the backup with duplicity and tried to restore it with duplicati? Then it is a simple answer: This does not work. Duplicati and duplicity are similar in the way they are working but they are not compatible.

Re cross platform you have 2 options: Use duplicity on Linux and duplicity on Cygwin on Windows. Or use Duplicati on Windows and Duplicati with Mono on Linux. But don't try to use Duplicati and duplicity with the same backups!

Answer (score -1):

I use [Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/), its free and open and works on Windows and Linux, and has extensive documentation on the linux and windows ports.

As for Duplicati, I have never used it so I cant really tell you what do on that, but you that is an alternative.